# Can this close reason be improved?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

One of our custom off topic close reasons is the following:

> Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem.

However, isn't the purpose of this site to gain understanding?

The basic purpose of this close reason is obvious, it's to get rid of "TEACH ME TO HACK FACEBOOK!!!111"-type posts<sup>1</sup>. However, black hat posts seem to be allowed (see [Clarify our stance on black hat questions](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/897/clarify-our-stance-on-black-hat-questions) and the linked meta posts)

Does anyone have any better wordings for this? (Or is it OK to keep the current one) It should capture the blackhat policy succinctly.

<sup>1. These close reasons were put in place by the community team after looking at a list of recently closed questions, so it ought to be common enough a close reason.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“too broad” + downvote generally covers it.

The kind of questions we want to close are the ones that are unsalvageable, and the real problem isn't that they're about breaking security but that the asker doesn't have a clue and what he's asking is way beyond his reach.

Script kiddie questions make the bulk of these way-over-your-head-and-we-can't-help-you questions, but we do also get the occasional “how do I make my system secure?” question with no information about threats, assets, etc. even in layman language.

I don't think Security.SE needs any custom off-topic close reason. Just leave the default in place.

Answer (score -2):

Whatabout:

> Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system without
>   demonstrating an understanding of the concepts involved and without
>   clearly identifying a specific problem, are considered off-topic.

Comment: That's more or less the same thing :P